# How can I compare different files without opening them?

Tags: shell-script, files, scripting, diff

I have two directories A and B; each one contains a lot of sub-directories

```
geom001, geom002 ....etc
```

each sub-directory contains a file named results. I want to compare, without opening any of them, each file in A with each file in B and find if there is a file or more in A similar to one or more file in B.
How can I use command like the following in a loop to search over all files?

```
cmp --silent  file1 file2  || echo "file1 and file2 are different"
```

Comment: Erm, "without opening" a file the comparison options are limited to `stat` values, e.g. the file size and modification date. "More similar" sounds like you would need to open the files and compare the contents somehow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rsync compare directories?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57305/rsync-compare-directories)

Comment: FYI, you can't compare the contents of two files without opening them.  That's axiomatic.

Comment: Also, what, exactly, do you mean by 'similar'?  exactly the same?  if not, how much and/or what kind of difference is allowed before a file is no longer considered to be similar?  different only by white space?  less than X lines/bytes different? or something else.

Comment: exactly the same in everything even space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If files are exactly the same, then their `md5sum`s will be exactly the same, so you can use:

```
find A/ B/ -type f -exec md5sum {} + | sort | uniq -w32 -D
```

An md5sum is always exactly 128 bits (or 16 bytes or 32 hex digits) long, and the `md5sum` program output uses hex digits.  So we use the `-w32` option on the `uniq` command to compare only the first 32 characters on each line.

This will print **all** files with a non-unique md5sum.  i.e. duplicates.

NOTE: this will detect duplicate files no matter where they are in A/ or B/ - so if `/A/subdir1/file` and `A/subdir2/otherfile` are the same, they will still be printed.  If there are multiple duplicates, they will all be printed.

You can remove the md5sums from the output by piping into, e.g., `awk '{print $2}'` or with `cut` or `sed` etc.  I've left them in the output because they're a useful key for an associative array (aka a 'hash') in `awk` or `perl` etc for further processing.

Answer (score 1):

The seeming challenges of the question / request is perhaps the recursion aspect.

Assuming that `cmp` is an adequate utility and that both folder / directories `1` & `2` to be compared are of the same structure (ie same files & folders) and reside within the same root path - you can try something similar to:

```
#!/bin/bash
ROOT=$PWD ; # #// change to absolute path eg: /home/aphorise/my_files
PWD1="1/*" ;
PWD2="2/*" ;

# #// Get lengths of seperators
IFS=/ read -a DP <<< ${ROOT} ;
PLEN1=${#DP[*]} ;
IFS=/ read -a DP <<< ${PWD1} ;
PLEN1=$(echo "${#DP[*]}" + $PLEN1 - 1 | bc) ;
IFS=/ read -a DP <<< ${PWD2} ;
PLEN2=${#DP[*]} ;

# #// Set absolute paths:
PWD1="${ROOT}/${PWD1}" ;
PWD2="${ROOT}/${PWD2}" ;
DIFFS=0 ;

function RECURSE()
{
    for A_FILE in $1 ; do
        if [ -d $A_FILE ] ; then
            RECURSE "$A_FILE/*" ;
        else
            IFS=/ read -a FP <<< ${A_FILE} ;
            B_FILE="${PWD2:0:${#PWD2}-${#PLEN2}}$( IFS=/ ; printf "%s" "${FP[*]:$PLEN1:512}"; )" ;
            if ! cmp ${A_FILE} ${B_FILE} 1>/dev/null ; then printf "$A_FILE --> $B_FILE <-- DIFFER.\n" ; ((++DIFFS)) ; fi ;
        fi ;
    done ;
}

printf "Starting comparison on $PWD1 @ $(date)\n\n" ;
RECURSE "${PWD1[*]}" ;
if ((DIFFS != 0)) ; then printf "\n= $DIFFS <= differences detected.\n" ; fi ;
printf "\nCompleted comparison @ $(date)\n" ;
```

### UPDATE:

Following with another script - subsequent to additional feedback received - to unconditionally compare all files in directory `1` with `2`:

```
#!/bin/bash
PWD1="$PWD/1/*" ;
PWD2="$PWD/2/*" ;
DIFFS=0 ;
NODIFFS=0 ;

printf "Starting comparison on $PWD1 @ $(date)\n\n" ;

FILES_A=$(find ${PWD1} -type f) ;
FILES_B=$(find ${PWD2} -type f) ;

for A_FILE in ${FILES_A[*]} ; do
        for B_FILE in ${FILES_B[*]} ; do
                if ! cmp ${A_FILE} ${B_FILE} 1>/dev/null ; then
                        printf "$A_FILE & $B_FILE <- DIFFER.\n" ;
                        ((++DIFFS)) ;
                else
                        printf "\n-> SAME: $A_FILE & $B_FILE\n" ;
                        ((++NODIFFS)) ;
                fi ;
        done ;
done ;

printf "\n= $DIFFS <= differences detected - & - $NODIFFS <= exact matches.\n" ;
printf "\nCompleted comparison @ $(date)\n" ;
```

Comment: well, but it doesn't see the files in directory 2, _/home/mohsin//1/geom001/results.dat --> /home/mohsin//2/ <-- DIFFER._ also it just compares each file with the corresponding one in the second directory e.g. it compares_1/geom001/results.dat with 2/geom001/results.dat and not with 1/geom00{2..n}/results.dat_

Comment: So if I'm understanding you correctly you dont not have identical file structures with differing file-tree / directory structures and for each file in directory `1` you'd like a find & compare in `2` for all files that are named the same?

Comment: yes, what I want is to compare each file in 1 with all files in 2, sorry _1/geom00{2..n}/results.dat_ should be _2/geom00{2..n}/results.dat_ in the previous comment

Comment: Just those that are the same name or all files irrespective of their naming? - Ie for each file in `1` you'd want it compared to *all* files in path / sub-paths of `2`?

Comment: yes, irrespective of their naming; each file in the first with all files in the second directory.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will get you close. It will list out the cmp output for all files named results in A compared to all files named results in B.

```
find ./A -name results | xargs -I REPLACESTR find ./B -name results -exec cmp REPLACESTR {} \;
```